# hibernate read only queries cache mechanism

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, caching

This question is related to my other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14682395/hibernate-cache-for-scalar-queries)

I am building a Spring web application which reads data from DB using hibernate. My App will not be aware of any changes(Updates/Inserts) done to the DB. Is there a way to use query cache in such a scenario?

I configured query cache, and it is not invalidating the cache when I update the DB from different App. And I *think* it is the expected behavior.

I need the queries to be cached and invalidated when there is an update in DB. How to achieve this?

Comment: You can try looking into Terracotta, SwarmCache, TreeCache with replication etc for clustered cache.

Comment: @NayanWadekar: Thanks. will look into them

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure is there any automatic way for refreshing the cache. But i have solved this problem in my last project. Expose a method like below and give access to admin. Once any modification done in DB externally call this method to refresh your cache.

```
public void refreshCache()
    {
        try {
            Map<String, ClassMetadata> classesMetadata = sessionFactory.getAllClassMetadata();
            for (String entityName : classesMetadata.keySet()) {

                sessionFactory.evictEntity(entityName);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I am planning to do now. My queries are not entity based, hence am evicting all query regions. However I would be happy to implement if there is some other way to do this automatically without a maintenance overhead :).

Answer (score 0):

Well if you are using Oracle , the following command will give you the last updated unique scn on the table

```
select max(ora_rowscn) from TableName;
```

**output**

```
10772982279880
```

further you convert this to timestamp if you want

```
select scn_to_timestamp(10772982279880) from dual
```

but idont think you need to convert it into time , just cache the the rowscn alone and periodically check the table , if there is a change you can evict the cache regions.

```
Please note that this supports version > 10g
```